# Android Activity Tear down rebuild

Tags: android, android-activity

Under some circumstances I need to be able to tear down all my activities that are in my application stack and recreate them all due to configuration changes. I have accomplished this by first calling finish for each activity and then recreating the stack.

To recreate, I relauch my root activity. And within its onStart I have it create my second activity. Within my second activities onStart I have it create my third Activity. This does work but the problem that I am having is that when watching the screen you see each of the three activities created and animate into the next activity. I want to have this rebuilding invisible to the user and hide these transitions. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android already takes care of restarting activities when there is a configuration change.

If you are saying you want all of your activities to be restarted, even if they aren't currently visible (Android will do this lazily as the user returns them and they become visible, if the configuration is still different at that point), then no there is no simple way to do this.  I can't imagine you coming up with anything that isn't going to be hideously ugly, because to get the platform to restart your activity you will need to make it visible, and then you are going to have flicker up the wazoo.

Things just aren't intended to work that way.  This isn't how pretty much any other application you run on Android will operate, so if you deeply feel like it is something you need to do then it will be useful to explain why that is so we can tell you a better way to accomplish what you want. :)  For example, if you have a bunch of activities whose state is fundamentally tied together to require this, consider using fragments instead (or cleaning that up).

On the other hand, if you just have some internal concept of a configuration and want to get your activity to be restarted (say for example to switch between themes), there is an API for this but it only was added in Android 3.0: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. When I say configuration change I do not mean an Android configuration change. I mean the user changed a settings in my app that requires a teardown and rebuild. With two different configurations I still have the same screens such as Main Screen, Settings Screen etc. but the content will change drastically based on configuration. To facilitate this change I use a factory to make my activites. When the configuration changes I want to swap out the factory, and recreate all existing screens using the new factory in place.

Comment: @metalideath: "To facilitate this change I use a factory to make my activites." -- considering that you don't "make" *any* activities in Android, I believe that you have mis-phrased this. "recreate all existing screens using the new factory in place" -- if you are willing to lose the back stack, use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in an `Intent` with `startActivity()` to eliminate all other activities, which will then rebuild when next used. Otherwise, you will need to use a static data member or something and repopulate your activities in `onResume()`.